# Can't resize partition: "You can't perform this resize unless it has a booter"

Tags: partition, high-sierra, core-storage

I have an external 1TB disk that I use for Time Machine backups that I temporarily added a second 100GB partition to. After deleting the partition, though, I can't reclaim the free space. Disk Utility won't let me drag the partition button onto it:

[image]

I tried the `resizeStack` command, but got an error:

```
******:~ ******$ diskutil cs resizeStack 389D8763-4C1B-4D77-A734-C507DBD567C1 0g
The Core Storage Logical Volume UUID is 389D8763-4C1B-4D77-A734-C507DBD567C1
Started CoreStorage operation
Error: -69722: You can't perform this resize unless it has a booter (target partition is probably too small)
```

What's this business about a 'booter'? How can I reclaim my lost 100GB?

EDIT:

Output from `diskutil list`:

```
/dev/disk3 (external, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *1.0 TB     disk3
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk3s1
   2:          Apple_CoreStorage Time Machine            900.0 GB   disk3s2
```

... and from `diskutil cs  list`:

```
+-- Logical Volume Group 7DBE7E68-7EB4-4208-9BBF-1ED08259754F
    =========================================================
    Name:         Time Machine
    Status:       Online
    Size:         899995127808 B (900.0 GB)
    Free Space:   0 B (0 B)
    |
    +-< Physical Volume 38259B44-99D7-4F3C-973D-2510408E8E72
    |   ----------------------------------------------------
    |   Index:    0
    |   Disk:     disk3s2
    |   Status:   Online
    |   Size:     899995127808 B (900.0 GB)
    |
    +-> Logical Volume Family 76E4A480-E849-47D0-96D8-D07940EAB3C7
        ----------------------------------------------------------
        Encryption Type:         AES-XTS
        Encryption Status:       Unlocked
        Conversion Status:       Complete
        High Level Queries:      Fully Secure
        |                        Passphrase Required
        |                        Accepts New Users
        |                        Has Visible Users
        |                        Has Volume Key
        |
        +-> Logical Volume 389D8763-4C1B-4D77-A734-C507DBD567C1
            ---------------------------------------------------
            Disk:                  disk4
            Status:                Online
            Size (Total):          899642802176 B (899.6 GB)
            Revertible:            No
            LV Name:               Time Machine
            Volume Name:           Time Machine
            Content Hint:          Apple_HFS
```

Comment: Start by posting the output from `diskutil list`. Edit your question and paste the output. After posting, you probably will be asked to post the output from other commands.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Note: This answer assumes your drive is not hybrid partitioned. In other words, I assume your drive is using a GUID partitioning scheme and the Master Boot Record (MBR) table is fully protected. Also, I assume the sector size is 512 bytes.

I will use an approximately 500 GB spare image file to illustrate your problem and my solution. The output from `diskutil disk1` and `diskutil disk2` for my drive is shown below. Here, there is almost no free space.

```
/dev/disk1 (disk image):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        +500.0 GB   disk1
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk1s1
   2:          Apple_CoreStorage Macbook HD              499.1 GB   disk1s2
   3:                 Apple_Boot Recovery HD             650.0 MB   disk1s4

/dev/disk2 (disk image):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                  Apple_HFS Macbook HD             +498.8 GB   disk2
                                 Logical Volume on disk1s2
                                 06A8BD94-5D42-4A7A-A8DF-2FAB7A268153
                                 Unlocked Encrypted
```

Normally, a `Apple_CoreStorage` partition is followed by a `Apple_Boot` partition. Your drive is missing this `Apple_Boot` partition.

> Note: Other Core Storage configurations will use a different name and size for this `Apple_Boot` partition. For example, the partition may appear with the name `Boot OS X` and a size of `134.2 MB`.

Below is output from the same commands, but this time my drive has approximately 50 GB of free space. Furthermore, the `Apple_Boot` partition is missing.

```
/dev/disk1 (disk image):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        +500.0 GB   disk1
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk1s1
   2:          Apple_CoreStorage Macbook HD              449.9 GB   disk1s2
   3:                 Apple_Boot Recovery HD             650.0 MB   disk1s3

/dev/disk2 (disk image):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                  Apple_HFS Macbook HD             +449.5 GB   disk2
                                 Logical Volume on disk1s2
                                 06A8BD94-5D42-4A7A-A8DF-2FAB7A268153
                                 Unlocked Encrypted
```

Below are instructions for recreating the `Apple_Boot` partition and recovering the free space. When required, make the appropriate adjustments to these commands. These instructions will not recreate any important files that were stored in this partition. In your case, there may not have been any important files. If needed, prepend a `sudo` to any of these commands.

1. Use the third part tool [`gdisk`](https://www.rodsbooks.com/gdisk/download.html) to create the missing `Apple_Boot` partition. Enter the text given below to invoke this interactive command.

   ```
   gdisk /dev/disk1
   ```

   Below are the interactive gdisk commands. The blank line indicates the default was selected. You should expect your default value to be different from mine.

   ```
   n 
   3

   +1269536
   AB00
   w
   y
   ```

   Below is the output from when I used the `gdisk /dev/disk1` command.

   ```
   GPT fdisk (gdisk) version 1.0.3

   Warning: Devices opened with shared lock will not have their
   partition table automatically reloaded!
   Partition table scan:
     MBR: protective
     BSD: not present
     APM: not present
     GPT: present

   Found valid GPT with protective MBR; using GPT.

   Command (? for help): n
   Partition number (3-128, default 3): 3
   First sector (34-976562506, default = 879053752) or {+-}size{KMGTP}: 
   Last sector (879053752-976562506, default = 976562506) or {+-}size{KMGTP}: +1269536
   Current type is 'Apple HFS/HFS+'
   Hex code or GUID (L to show codes, Enter = AF00): AB00
   Changed type of partition to 'Recovery HD'

   Command (? for help): w

   Final checks complete. About to write GPT data. THIS WILL OVERWRITE EXISTING
   PARTITIONS!!

   Do you want to proceed? (Y/N): y
   OK; writing new GUID partition table (GPT) to /dev/disk1.
   Warning: Devices opened with shared lock will not have their
   partition table automatically reloaded!
   Warning: The kernel may continue to use old or deleted partitions.
   You should reboot or remove the drive.
   The operation has completed successfully.
   ```
2. Use the command below to format the newly created partition.

   ```
   newfs_hfs  -J  -v  "Recovery HD"  /dev/disk1s3
   ```
3. Use the command below to recover the free space. Note: I already substituted your logical volume UUID.

   ```
   diskutil  cs  resizestack  389D8763-4C1B-4D77-A734-C507DBD567C1  0
   ```

### Final note:

The `gpt` command can be used instead of the third party `gdisk` command. You would need to enter the `gpt` command shown below to partially dump the contents of the GUID Partition Table (GPT).

```
gpt  -r  show  /dev/disk1
```

For my drive, the output is shown below.

```
      start       size  index  contents
          0          1         PMBR
          1          1         Pri GPT header
          2         32         Pri GPT table
         34          6         
         40     409600      1  GPT part - C12A7328-F81F-11D2-BA4B-00A0C93EC93B
     409640  878644112      2  GPT part - 53746F72-6167-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC
  879053752   97508755         
  976562507         32         Sec GPT table
  976562539          1         Sec GPT header
```

From this output, determine the start of the free space after the `Apple_CoreStorage` (`53746F72-6167-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC`) partition. For my drive this would be sector `879053752`.

> Note: **In the `gpt` command given below, replace my value of `879053752` with your own value.**

The `gpt` command shown below adds a new `Apple_Boot` partition do the drive. Set the `-b` option to the start of the free space value. This command must be immediately preceded by the `diskutil` command shown below.

> Note: If necessary, the `-b` option needs rounded up to a value evenly divisible by 8.

```
diskutil  umountdisk  disk1
gpt  add  -i  3  -b  879053752  -s  1269536  -t  426F6F74-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC  /dev/disk1
```

Next, proceed to step 2.

Comment: Great, that did it, @David! Many thanks for your help, I had been struggling with that for days.

Comment: Out of curiosity, though, is the new Apple_Boot "Recovery HD" bootable? Can I make it bootable?

Comment: Step 2 formatted the `Apple_Boot` partition, therefore this partition has no files and is not bootable. You should post the question: Can macOS be installed in a external core storage partition be used by Time Machine?

Comment: This answer worked for me but I did it slightly different. I, indeed, had a "Apple_Boot / Recovery HD" after my "Apple_CoreStorage" but something must have been wrong with it, that I got the "... unless it has a booter". So I started by deleting my existing "Recovery HD" partition. I couldn't find gdisk for Mac so I booted from a Ubuntu 16.04 USB and went thru the "gdisk" procedure. Then that "newfs_hfs" command failed saying it's not permitted (even with sudo), so I omitted that step. But after all it successfully resized my Volume. If anyone asks I can write this up as a different answer.