# Shrinking a Core Storage volume without the booter partition

Tags: hard-drive, disk-utility, partition, core-storage, hfs+

I have a 14 TB external drive containing a single 14 TB HFS+ encrypted partition (besides EFI). I cannot resize this partition to add a new one. When I tried using either Disk Utility or `diskutil`, it says

> You can’t perform this resize unless it has a booter (target partition is probably too small)

Essentially I am having the same issue as described in this question: [Can't resize partition: "You can't perform this resize unless it has a booter"](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/315514/cant-resize-partition-you-cant-perform-this-resize-unless-it-has-a-booter)

However, the answer to that question does not work for my scenario because *there is no unallocated space after the single partition* and I cannot manually add the booter using `gdisk` or `gpt` because of that.

My question is,

- is there other ways to shrink this partition, besides moving everything out and reformatting it. Or,
- how do I add in the required booter partition (so that I can resize normally using Disk Utility)?

Note that this is a Core Storage volume because it is encrypted.

- I had the idea of forcibly creating a new GPT table where there is enough space for the booter, but I haven't done that because I don't know how that would affect the existing partition.
- I also tried using `diskutil cs resizeVolume`, which will resize the inner Logical Volume, and then I could add another Logical Volume after it. The problem is that these two volumes will then share the same encryption key AFAIK, which is not desirable.

---

FYI, here are all the things that have happened that put me in this situation:

- This is a brand new 14 TB hard drive. I originally formatted it into two partitions: one 10TB and one 4TB. Both were HFS+ journaled encrypted (so they were Core Storage volumes).
- Later, I attempted to resize them into 12TB/2TB using Disk Utility, **which failed miserably.**
- After this, the second 4TB partition could not be found, and the first one could not be mounted. This was reported by `diskutil cs info` about the first partition (originally 10TB):

  ```
  |
  +-- Logical Volume Group 69E42F2B-A2E4-41EC-93A9-4D62C0C9082B
  |   =========================================================
  |   Name:         -none-
  |   Status:       Initializing
  |   Size:         0 B (0 B)
  |   Free Space:   -none-
  |   |
  |   +-< Physical Volume 4BBFE85D-06C3-4285-98D9-D6D30E3E4031
  |       ----------------------------------------------------
  |       Index:    0
  |       Disk:     disk2s2
  |       Status:   Failed
  |       Size:     14000175669248 B (14.0 TB)
  ```
- However, I managed to completely recover the first partition (filesystem intact and `fsck` passed), by **destroying and recreating the GPT table, in which the first partition occupies the entire disk** — that is, the end of the partition is now right before the secondary GPT. Now the GPT looks like this:

  ```
        start         size  index  contents
            0            1         PMBR
            1            1         Pri GPT header
            2           32         Pri GPT table
           34            6
           40       409600      1  GPT part - C12A7328-F81F-11D2-BA4B-00A0C93EC93B
       409640  27344355255      2  GPT part - 53746F72-6167-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC
  27344764895           32         Sec GPT table
  27344764927            1         Sec GPT header
  ```
- *And now I cannot resize the 14TB partition.*

Comment: Have you tried determining what physical volume size is stored in the core storage header? If this is smaller than current core storage partition size, then you could use the `gpt` command to set the partition size to this value in sectors. In other words, try to undo what you did to create this problem.

Comment: @DavidAnderson Thanks. I followed the specification from [here](https://github.com/libyal/libfvde/blob/master/documentation/FileVault%20Drive%20Encryption%20(FVDE).asciidoc#4-volume-header), and I got a physical volume size of 27344355248 blocks, which is 3584 bytes (7 blocks) less than the size of the partition. That wouldn't be enough for the usual Boot OS X partition which is 134.2 MB though.

Answer (score 2):

I followed [David Anderson's advice](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/405866/shrinking-a-core-storage-volume-without-the-booter-partition#comment564126_405866) and discovered that the partition (as described by GPT) is 3584 bytes (7 LBA blocks) larger than the Core Storage Physical Volume. Using this information, I did manage to shrink the volume to add a second partition.

**The process is, however, quite scary: it involves a kernel panic, then some more cryptic, unhelpful, unfixable `diskutil` errors, and then yet some more frightening failures.**

*And so let this be an anti-answer:*

- if you are dealing with an Apple-designed filesystem (such as HFS and APFS),
- and you don't have professional knowledge of the inner workings of them,
- and you find your volume in an inconsistent state — *it should be considered inconsistent as soon as Disk Utility starts complaining* —
- and yet the volume is somehow still usable (you can see your files and such):

Then, for the love of your data and your well-being, instead of trying to fix the problem by meddling with the volume header or partition table (like I did),

## Just move everything out and reformat.

---

I eventually lost no data. Here is my process. I hope that people more knowledgeable than me could point out all the mistakes I made.

*Note: 1 block is 512 bytes.*

- (First, I made a copy of the first 512 bytes of the partition, which contains the Volume Header, using `dd`).
- Using the `gpt` command, I learned that my second GPT partition (the main partition) has a size of `27344355255` blocks; following this [specification of Core Storage](https://github.com/libyal/libfvde/blob/master/documentation/FileVault%20Drive%20Encryption%20(FVDE).asciidoc#4-volume-header) (which is the abstraction layer that allows HFS encryption), I examined the partition volume header and learned that the Core Storage Physical Volume only occupies `27344355248` blocks. This means there was an extra space of 7 blocks.
- I then decided to free these 7 blocks by recreating the GPT table (using the `gpt` command), also marking the type of the new partition as [Apple Boot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table#Partition_type_GUIDs).
- I attempted to create an HFS+ volume on the new partition using `diskutil`. **This is not possible because an HFS+ volume requires a minimum of 512 KB.**
- With the unformatted Apple Boot partition, I made the risky move of asking Disk Utility to resize the 14 TB partition. *This time, Disk Utility did not complain about missing booters.* **However, before the resizing had finished, a kernel panic struck.**
- After restarting, `diskutil` reported that the original 14 TB partition is now 12 TB, still intact. The 7-block Apple Boot partition now occupied the remaining 2 TB free space, still unformatted.
- Then, I modified the GPT table again, this time adding a `262144`-block Apple Boot partition after the now 12 TB partition, and another Core Storage partition taking up the remaining space.
- At this point, both the 12 TB and 2 TB partition is showing up in Disk Utility. Upon reformatting the 2 TB partition as a JHFS+ encrypted volume (so that it too has a booter), both partitions can be resized freely using Disk Utility with no errors.
- **The only caveat was that using First Aid (`diskutil verifyVolume`) on the 12 TB volume now persistently reported the error "Incorrect size for volume"** (right after it says the volume "appears to be OK", too). This could not be fixed using any `diskutil` command. But despite the error, the two volumes can still be resized and normally mounted.
- At this point, it would seem that my original question has been solved, to a large extent.

This is what the partition scheme now looked like:

```
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER 
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *14.0 TB    disk2 
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk2s1 
   2:          Apple_CoreStorage - Main Partition -      12.0 TB    disk2s2 
   3:                 Apple_Boot Boot OS X               134.2 MB   disk2s3 
   4:          Apple_CoreStorage Time Machine            2.0 TB     disk2s4 
   5:                 Apple_Boot Boot OS X               134.2 MB   disk2s5
```

---

(The rest of this is me not knowing what I am doing.)

- After this, I came up with the hypothesis that the "Incorrect volume size" error that Disk Utility kept complaining about was about the Logical Volume, and not the Physical Volume.

  - Core Storage has many abstraction layers, the order of which is Physical Volume → Logical Volume Group → Logical Volume Family → Logical Volume.
  - If I am understanding it correctly, PV is the closest to the GPT partition, LVF is where FileVault encryption occurs, and LV is the volume that users can see.
- To test this out, I deleted the 2 TB partition via Disk Utility. There was no issue. The hard drive now contained EFI, the 14 TB partition, and the 134.2 MB booter.
- I attempted to use `diskutil cs resizeVolume` to resize only the Logical Volume back to 12 TB, and not the Physical Volume. **The resizing could not proceed because of the "Incorrect volume size" error.** (The same went for `diskutil cs resizeStack`).
- Then I had the **horrible** idea to revert not only the GPT table, but also the Core Storage volume header, to the state when this question was posted.

  - This is in the hope that `diskutil verifyVolume` will then auto-adjust the volume size, and then I can start over the process, but resize the Logical Volume first.
  - I made a backup of the current volume header, then `dd` rewrote the first 512 bytes of the volume using the backup `.img` file I made of the header at the start of this answer.
  - **After I did that, the 14 TB volume once again was unmountable.** All `diskutil` operations would fail at this point.
- I attempted to revert this change by writing the 512-byte volume header back. **Then, another kernel panic occurred.**
- **This time, things got much more serious. For the next few hours, every time I connected the hard drive to my laptop, macOS immediately kernel panicked — whether it was in normal mode, Recovery, Safe Mode, or Single User Mode.**
- I tried booting into Ubuntu from USB, and examine and manipulate the Volume Header from there, to no avail.
- I almost lost hope, when I remembered that, back when the partition first failed, I ran `dd` through the first few GBs of the partition and saved it as an image, which was since deleted. I recovered it using Disk Drill, and after painfully comparing hex dumps, **I decided to copy the first `62500` blocks (32 MB) of the image file back to the partition.**

  - My idea was that this would cause macOS to recognize the volume in the same way that it recognized the original 14 TB volume when it first failed, and then if I redo the steps I described in the question (recreating the GPT table), I could get the volume back a second time, and I thought that the worst that could happen is I would lose all file changes since the partition first failed.
- **Shockingly, not only did this recover the partition, but all the files that were on the hard drive before I broke the partition the second time are still there.**
- Now I am in the process of backing up everything so that I can start the hard drive fresh.

---

#### To reiterate: when in the slightest doubt, backup!